# product.number for user_id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a question for rails.

I have a User controller,
I have a Product controller.

I have a user id references in product:db.

How to puts User.product number in Html?

Comment: put it in hidden_field

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need configure devise gem for authentication to your user model to add user_id column to your products table.

```
rails g migartion add_user_id_to_products user_id:integer:index
```

In your users model

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many  :products
 end
```

In your products model

```
 class Products < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :user

 end
```

As your user and products are associated through has_many and belongs_to.
you can as below in the products controller

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index

 @products = Product.all 
end

def new

  @product = Product.new

end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params)


    if @product.save

     redirect_to edit_product_path(@product), notice: "Saved..."



    else
         render :new 

    end

  end


private


def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit( :title, :description, :category)
end

end
```

If the data is successfully saved into the database, you will find the user_id column of the products table filled with the id of the current_user.

To get all the products of a particular user

In your users controller show action

```
def show

 @user_products = @user.products

end
```

The @user_products will have all the products belonging to the corresponding user.